# Java Stream - Compile time Error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Integer,List<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream, collectors

I hava a simple code where i am converting a List of my custom class object into a Map>.
The code is as follows:

```
List<NPDto> appList = new ArrayList<NPDto>(); 
//list gets populated though some other method

//Here is conerting code where i get compile time error
final Map<Integer, List<String>> appMap = appList.stream()
                                              .collect(
                                                Collectors.toMap(
                                                  np -> NumberUtils.toInt(np.getPId()),
                                                  np -> Arrays.asList(np.getAppsReceived().split(","))
                                              ));
// Here is my DTO                                              
public class NPDto {

    private String pId;
  private String appsReceived;

  public String getPId(){
    return pId;
  }

  public void setPId(String pId){
    this.pId = pId;
  }

  public String getAppsReceived(){
    return appsReceived;
  }

  public void setAppsReceived(String appsReceived){
    this.appsReceived = appsReceived;
  }
}
```

But, i am getting a compiler error as follows:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Integer,List<String>>
```

> I am compiling with Java SE 8[1.8.0_91]

Don't know where i am wrong. Can anybody please help out?

Comment: Why you people are down voting? Give me a reason.

Comment: Not my downvote but probably because you haven't shown us a [mcve]. In particular show us the actual declarations of the getters in `NPDto`. Using incorrect method names can give this error.

Comment: @greg-449 Added the getter and setter also.

Comment: You are missing a right parenthesis (the one that closes the `collect` method call). If it's a typo in your question, then include which compiler you are using (javac / Eclipse's compiler / ...), knowing that the latter may have problems with type inference. Compiles fine for me using javac 1.8.0_102.

Comment: @KaranVerma The code you added does not even compile.

Comment: .. then include which compiler you are using.

Comment: @AlexisC. I am using Java SE 8[1.8.0_91]

Comment: It should compile with javac 1.8.0_91. Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a slight change as split returns a **String []**.

```
np -> Arrays.asList(np.getAppsReceived().split(","))
```

Comment: That is what i am converting this into a List using Arrays.asList

Comment: @KaranVerma that's funny I took the same code you have and it compiles just file. What does NumberUtils return? an Integer I assume?

Comment: Yes it returns Integer.

Comment: I guess, its commons.apache `NumberUtils.toInt`, designed to make erroneous code even worse by silently converting `null` and empty strings to zeros…